# How remove <p> and <br> from the_excerpt()?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a short description by post but when I try to display description wordpress adds `<p>` or `<br>` or `<strong>`, how remove? Look at this pic:

[image]

and my code is that:

```
        </span>
            <span class="address-place">
             <?php echo the_excerpt (); ?>
             <hr>
        </span>
```

Comment: Anything you tried? if yes then show

Comment: Yes i tried all i find on google but the same result

Answer (score 4):

[`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) seems to be what you're looking for:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(the_excerpt()); ?>
```

Comment: don't you think better to give comment, and wait till he not paste some code that he tried?

Comment: Is possible if the post is copy paste from the another site to put that tags?

Comment: Awesome! that was the correct answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here. Maybe it will be useful for someone.
`get_the_excerpt()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myExcerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
$myExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", $myExcerpt);
?>
</span>
<span class="address-place">
<?php   echo $myExcerpt; ?>
<hr>
</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This way I implemented it myself and it worked.

`<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());?>`